# Pynsee 400 - Bad Request Query API

Tags: python, list, bad-request

I want to use the python package "Pynsee" to download a list of French companies, but I get the following error message "RequestException: Error 400 - Bad Request Query" followed by an incomplete URL.

I don't know where this can come from, I made several assumptions and I know that the API identifiers are correct, that the requested servers are operational. So I guess it's the syntax of my request.

However, I followed the tutorial provided by the developers. I think that my error comes from the pattern argument and the list that I insert in this argument.... but I can't find any solution.

Error code :
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wctoa.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVk1P.png)

Pynsee docs : https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/example_doctors_idf.html

My code : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/danKF.png) and Block

```
# Chargement des référentiels géographiques des iris pour obtenir les codes communes
iris_codecom = pd.read_excel('reference_IRIS_geo2022.xlsx')
iris_codecom.rename(columns={"CODE_IRIS": "IRIS"}, inplace=True)

# Fusion des iris utilisées avec le référentiel pour obtenir les codes communes
selected_com = pd.merge(iris_codecom, selected_iris, on=['IRIS'], how='inner')

# Production d'une liste des codes communes pour lancer la fonction pynsee search_sirene
selected_com_list = selected_com ['DEPCOM'].unique().tolist()
selected_com_list = "|".join(selected_com_list)

print(selected_com_list)
```

```
# Set up des tokens API
from pynsee.utils.init_conn import init_conn
init_conn(insee_key="***************", insee_secret="****************")

# Nettoyage du caches des datas
from pynsee.utils import clear_all_cache; clear_all_cache()

# On importe l'outil de requête search_sirene
from pynsee.sirene import search_sirene

# Sélection des données sirene selon la liste des départements 
export = search_sirene(variable = ["activitePrincipaleEtablissement","codePostalEtablissement"], 
                            pattern = [('47.22Z'), selected_com_list])

export_2 = search_sirene(variable = ["activitePrincipaleEtablissement","codePostalEtablissement"], 
                          pattern = [('10.13B'), selected_com_list])

concat_df = pd.concat([export, export_2], ignore_index=True)

# suppression des doublons dans la clé primaire Siret
concat_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['siret'])

# Utiliser la méthode "isin" de pandas pour créer un masque booléen
#compare = concat_df['activitePrincipaleEtablissement'].isin(list_pattern)

# filtrer le dataframe avec le masque booléen pour récupérer les lignes correspondantes
#result= concat_df[compare]

result = concat_df.get_location()

# enregistrer le resultat au format csv.
result.to_csv(r'C:\Users\*******\Documents\Dossier script python\EI_geoloc_sirene.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

display(result)
```

Thank you in advance !

I already tried to see if it was an API problem, but it is not. I think it's a problem with the pattern argument of the search_sirene() function

I also tried to modify my list, but nothing works.

Comment: I dont know if that's the problem but the example shows the pattern should be a list of string : https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_data.html?highlight=sirene#pynsee.sirene.search_sirene and you are sending a tuple in your pattern as first element of your list.